# Model-View-ViewModel что это?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

Подскажите пожалуйста, что такое Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)? Я понимаю, что это какой-то паттерн, но все эти определения в википедии мне не понять, кто нибудь может пожалуйста объяснить это как для чайника, если возможно то с примерами. Спасибо.

С уважением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это паттерн, в основе которого лежат события изменения состояния объекта для синхронизации изменений. Предположим, что есть программа с моделью данных, пользовательским интерфейсом и бизнес-логикой. При изменении модели меняются данные пользовательского интерфейса. При изменении пользовательского интерфейса меняются данные модели.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делается это ради того, чтобы бизнес логика была абсолютно отделима от пользовательского интерфейса и не занималась его обновлением. Таким образом, можно создавать сложные компоненты пользовательского интерфейса с простой интеграцией логики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой вопрос, что применение MVVM требует проектирования достаточно сложной модели данных (значительно сложнее той, что применена в том же [redux](https://hackernoon.com/restate-the-story-of-redux-tree-27d8c5d1040a)), а код получается ОЧЕНЬ громоздким (менее чем в MVC, но наследует грабли уже в виде нагромождения событий)